# i want to change rect UIImage to polygon image with different shape

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I want to draw a rectangular UIImage to a polygon UIImage.
Like below example.
[image: Rectangular Image]

to 
[image: Final image i want]

Comment: how? I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

you will have to look into OpenGL ES, this will definately be able to draw textures onto a plain surface which is tilted, and most likely its your only option
. plus, the advantage being, you can actually animate the tilt in motion, like on coverflow

im not sure quartz can do it, but you will have to check that.

Comment: thanks for your reply. but i don't have idea about OpenGL ES. any hint how we can develop using OpenGL ES.